Is the inferential challenge of dense bayesian or markov networks solved after current improvements in variational inference and neural networks?
I am trying to understand more about Graphical models, and have a reasonable grasp of the basics now.
One issue that recurs in a lot of the papers of the mid-2000s and even in Koller's textbook is that we want sparsity in graphical models, to accelerate the speed of inference. So dense graphical model or "wide" graphical models make methods like clique-tree belief propagation very slow. Indeed, Koller suggests that one of the challenges in structure learning in Bayesian networks was that structure learning usually produces dense models that are hare to run exact and approximate inference algorithms over.
However, two innovations seem to have changed the calculus of these dense models. First, with variational inference we are actually able to train the inference model offline. So we learn the parameters of the variational distribution that emulates the full bayesian network. The variational distribution is fast to compute, and gives us approximate answers to queries that we submit to the network.
Second, neural networks--even small neural networks--can learn to approximate the results from exact inference of dense or wide models. Again, in an offline setting, we could generate random queries for a Bayesian network or Markov network and calculate exact inference on the queries. And then this would build a dataset for training a neural network to answer those queries as well.
Of course there are practical considerations in these methods, such as benchmarking the accuracy vis-a-vis exact or approximate inference on the original model. But those seems like manageable problems.
Hence my question is, now that variational methods and neural net methods are easy to implement, does that mean that the denseness of bayesian or markov networks is no longer an obstacle to the use of these models? Or are there still other issues that I am missing?
As an additional caveat, there are of course cases where variational inference or neural nets might not work. In those cases, then other algorithms would be necessary. But I am not sure how often--from a practical standpoint--that variational inference or neural nets fail to learn. So again it seems like the likely failure cases are probably a relatively small and specific class of situations.
